# Can't get i from for ((i = 0; i < koniec.length; i++) to index thru console.log(silnia(5)[i]);

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my JS script, I am trying to index thru silnia() a function that returns an array, I can do that manually without a problem: silnia(5)[1] but when I try to use an `i` from a for-loop it does not work.

```
koniec = [1,2,3];

for (i = 0; i < koniec.length; i++){
    // Returns only undefined:
    console.log(silnia(5)[i]);

    // Works no problem:
    // console.log(silnia(5)[2]);
}


function silnia(n){
    var wynikSilni = [];

    for(i = 1; i < (n + 1); i++){
        wynikSilni.push(i);
    }

    return wynikSilni;    
}
```

Comment: Think about what happens to `i` when `silnia` is called.

Comment: perfect example why `var` is not optional

Comment: You need to define `i` like this `let i = 0` or `var i = 0` before using it. And also koniec, `let koniec = [1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 2019 and [Arrays have quite a few helpful methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) that eliminate the need to set up and manage loop counters, which as others have pointed out, is the source of your problem.

[`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is the simplest of these and will help to greatly simplify your issue:

```js
koniec = [1,2,3];

// Loop over the knoiec array
// .forEach requires a callback function to execute
// upon each loop iteration. That function will automatically
// be passed 3 arguments: the array item, the item index, the array
koniec.forEach(function(item, index){
    console.log(silnia(5)[index]);
});


function silnia(n){
    var wynikSilni = [];

    for(i = 1; i < (n + 1); i++){
        wynikSilni.push(i);
    }

    return wynikSilni;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using a `var`, `let` or `const` statement to declare `i`, so it is considered a global variable.

Which means the same `i` you use in the `silnia` function is the same i being used in the `for` loop outside of it; essentially, the loop outside of it runs once, the silnia increments `i` to 6, and once it returns to the `for` loop in global scope, it stops because `i>koniec.length` (ETA: It then tries to access `sylnia(5)[6]` because `i` equals 6 at that point in time, which is undefined)

Try this:

```js
function silnia(n) {
    var wynikSilni = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < (n + 1); i++) {
        wynikSilni.push(i);
    }
    return wynikSilni;
}
koniec = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i = 0; i < koniec.length; i++) {
    // Returns only undefined:
    console.log(silnia(5)[i]);

    // Works no problem:
    // console.log(silnia(5)[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variables, otherwise you use global variables for all functions.

```js
function silnia(n) {
    var wynikSilni = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < (n + 1); i++) { // use var or let
        wynikSilni.push(i);
    }
    return wynikSilni;
}

var koniec = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i = 0; i < koniec.length; i++) { // use var or let
    console.log(silnia(5)[i]);
}
```